# Factor group isomorphic with Klein four-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of it which is an elementary abelian 2-group. Suppose that $G/N\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $|C_G(x)|=16$ for any $x\in G-N$. What can we say about $G$? Is it abelian? Is it elementary?

We know that since $G$ is a 2-group, it is nilpotent.

Comment: Could you give some motivation for this question?  It looks rather specific.  Certainly there is no reason for $G$ to be abelian, e.g. you could take a dihedral or quaternion group of order 8 and then stick on an elementary abelian direct factor in order to make the centralizers have the specified order.

Answer (score 3):

I would provide some examples, on which you may build some expectations:

- $G=C_2\times C_2\times D_4$, where $D_4$ is the dihedral group of $8$ elements. $N=C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ is the center of $G$. Since $D_4$ mod its center is $C_2\times C_2$, the factor group condition holds. For $x \in G-N$, $|C_G(x)|$ contains the $N$  and $x$, so its size is strictly larger than $8$. Also, $|C_G(x)|\neq 32$, otherwise $x$ is in the center. So $|C_G(x)|=16$ for any element not in the center.
- $G$ can be replaced by $C_2\times C_2\times Q_8$ ($Q_8$ is the quarernion group). The reasons are the same.
- There are [three](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C2.C4%5E2.html) [more](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C2xC2%5E2sC4.html) [groups](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C2xC4sC4.html) which can play the role of $G$, and $N$ their (respective) centralizers. The structure of $N$ and $G/N$  can be read off from the webpage; and for the size of the centralizer, you can use the formula $|C(x)|=\sum_{χ}|χ(x)|^2$, where $x$ is a conjugacy class and $χ$ runs over the group characters.